TabBar Item and Button has an light background
I have an simple TabView with some Tabs inside. Setting the Tab tint color to my custom color (some dark gray), the preview and simulator shows the expected correct appearance, but running the app on real device, the tab bar has an light background color. Also the custom buttons has also an light background color set.

I've already try to customise the UITabBar.appearance()
Here is the code for the TabView:
struct ContentView: View {

init() {
    let tabBarAppear = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppear.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    tabBarAppear.backgroundColor = UIColor.textLight

    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppear
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppear
    }
    
    
}

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Group {
            NavigationStack {
                CurrentRentedBooksView()
                    .navigationTitle("Aktuelle Bücher")
            }
            .tag(0)
            .tabItem {
                Label("Aktuell", systemImage: "book")
            }
            
            NavigationStack {
                ReadedBooksView()
                    .navigationTitle("Gelesene Bücher")
            }
            .tag(1)
            .tabItem {
                Label("Gelesen", systemImage: "eyeglasses")
            }
            
            NavigationStack {
                UnreadedBooksView()
                    .navigationTitle("Ungelesene Bücher")
            }
            .tag(2)
            .tabItem {
                Label("Ungelesen", systemImage: "eyeglasses.slash")
            }
        }
    }

    .tint(.grayElement)
    
}

}
And the custom Button:
Button {
   isLoading = true
   performAuthorSearch(for: book.author)
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle")
       .resizable()
       .foregroundStyle(.textLight)
       .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
       .background(LinearGradient(colors: [.lightRed, .lightBlue], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .trailing))
       .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
}

My device has latest version 17.5.1
Thanks

Looks like button shapes are turned on in the accessibility settings on the real device. Check Settings > Accessibility > Display & Text Size > Button Shapes

Thank you Benzy Neez, I spend so much hours to fix this "issue". You are brilliant.
